# Flexslider not loading viewport on edge conditions

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

So I seem to have an issue that I can replicate on all browsers, but using the chrome debugger, I was not able to find any issues.  No warnings or errors are produced.  Essentially the viewport will not load if I refresh the page and either minimize or change tabs quickly.  99 times out of 100 the viewport loads fine on Firefox under normal conditions but it is guaranteed to not load the viewport in the above scenario.  At first I thought it would be a race condition, but under the network tab, all resources are loading normally and exactly like under normal conditions.

So i have a slider that under normal conditions works with a slight inconsistency, that same inconsistency is consistently reproducible when I refresh a page and either change tabs or minimize the browser while loading the page.